# Can't use library with different Spring Boot version

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have an old main project in which I use Spring Boot version 1.3.5.RELEASE. In this project I would like to use a library that I've written. The library uses Spring Boot version 2.2.5.RELEASE.

I am using Gradle as the build tool. The project builds fine, but when I try to run it, I get the following error output:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [hr.kapsch.npgw.NpgwReferenceDatabaseApplication]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration$LegacyMetricRepositoryConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:609)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:110)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:811)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:808)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:779)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:192)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:319)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:236)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:275)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:95)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at hr.kapsch.npgw.NpgwReferenceDatabaseApplication.main(NpgwReferenceDatabaseApplication.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricRepositoryAutoConfiguration$LegacyMetricRepositoryConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:225)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:371)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:271)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:249)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:599)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attribute 'value' in annotation org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava should be compatible with org.springframework.boot.system.JavaVersion but a org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnJava$JavaVersion value was returned
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adaptForAttribute(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:536)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.adapt(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:461)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.getValue(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:401)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.TypeMappedAnnotation.asMap(TypeMappedAnnotation.java:286)
    at org.springframework.core.annotation.AbstractMergedAnnotation.asAnnotationAttributes(AbstractMergedAnnotation.java:193)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:106)
    at org.springframework.core.type.AnnotatedTypeMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(AnnotatedTypeMetadata.java:81)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnJavaCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnJavaCondition.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 25 common frames omitted
```

I've tried to search for solution. I didn't manage to find the exact same exception anywhere, but from what I found, I suspect the problem is that Spring Boot versions in the main project and in the library are not compatible. I've tried to search for information on compatibility of different Spring Boot versions, but didn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found out about [Semantic versioning](https://semver.org/). The first digit of the release signals the major release. Different major releases aren't backwards compatible (in my case 1 and 2). So in order to use the new library with the old project, I had to change Spring Boot version in new library to any version of major release 1.

Answer (score 1):

Mixing of spring versions is not good idea as it could lead to unexpected behaviour.
As spring with newer version have new classes etc. and using the lower version will lead to NoSuchMethodError or ClassNotFoundException.

It also can lead to some unpredictable exceptions at runtime.
Just to avoid such behaviour please use consistent and compatible spring boot versions.